# Browser IE :clicking on alert ok causes the dijit dialog in background to hide away visually

Tags: internet-explorer-8, dialog, dojo

I have a dijit dialog that pops up on clicking of a button. This dialog has a button which stands for submitting and one to hide the dialog On click of ok it sends a REST call and gets a response.

On error, an alert box is generated.

But what is happening here in IE 8 is that I need to explicitly again call a showdialog method to retain the dialog on screen.
What is expected behaviour is: when error occurs an alert box pops up and on click of ok the dialog in background retains. But this is not occuring normally. So I need to everytime check response and make an explicit call to show that dialog. If I do not call an explicit showdialog, the dialog simply visually seems nowhere(Gone!).

This is not a requirement if I use other browsers like chrome and FF which retain the dialog unless user himself cancels and hides them. 
This explicit calling may not have been a problem unless it caused the blink effect. That is it has some delay and then shows( a sec or two after ok click on alert).

Further adding to the woe is that when this error  scenario occurs and if user after clicking ok and then getting the dialog again after a blink follows and clicks cancel on dialog....poof! the behind screen that originally triggered that dialog still remains blurred! Hanging the browser!

Thanks & yes need a help, stuck on this!

Comment: @Rui thanks for the edit. I couldn't edit it this way though while typing i had left distinct statements yet it got submitted that way. Thanks for making it readable!